# IOS capability config. InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

Tags: java, ios, appium

I'm just configuring the capabilities of an IOS app and I'm not able to execute the App.I don't know if it's problem of the Xcode or the config

I tried with an Android app a similar code and works ok but with IOS always appears the same errorIt is "impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible"

public class Ios_Test {

```
    IOSDriver<IOSElement>driver;
    String path;

    public void setup()
    {
        System.out.println("Session is creating");
        path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "IOS");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Iphone 7");
        cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion","11.0");
        cap.setCapability("app", path+"//NDGapp.app");

        try {
            driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        }catch (MalformedURLException ex){
            System.out.print("exception");
        }
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Session is created");
    }
```

Comment: can you add the appium server log?

Comment: Already solved.It was a problem with the capabilities. I changed the device, the version and it workscap.setCapability("platformName", "IOS");
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Iphone Simulator");
            cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
            cap.setCapability("platformVersion","12.1");
            cap.setCapability("app", path+"//NDGApp.app");

Answer (score 0):

Already solved.It was a problem with the capabilities. I changed the device, the version and it works

```
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "IOS");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Iphone Simulator");
        cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion","12.1");
        cap.setCapability("app", path+"//NDGApp.app");
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to disable app transport security since your URL is not https

You can do it by adding this in the info.plist file

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
         <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
     </dict>
```